# What is the difference between pallet_elections_phragmen and sp_npos_solution?

Tags: npos, election

Just breezing through the docs for both crates, I can see that they both provide an implementation of phragmen's election algorithm, where `sp_npos_elections` provides an additional `PhragMMS` and `Balancing` algorithms, which I assume are different ways of electing from a voter snapshot.

In the substrate code base, we can see that for `election_provider_multi_phase` config, it takes a `Solver` from `frame_election_provider_support`. I could only see `pallet_election_phragmen` however being used in the `pallet_tips` Config.

I am confused why two separate implementations of phragmen election would be provided. If I were to look at this code for the first time my guess would've been that the `Solver` type should be define like so `type Solver = Elections` where Elections -> pallet_election_phragmen. But apparently that's not the case.

So between `frame_election_provider_support`, `sp_npos_elections`, and `pallet-elections-phragmen`, which is appropriate for what scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an overview of all of the named crates, and how they relate to one another.

[`sp-npos-elections`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_npos_elections/index.html): This is a generic rust crate that just implements a bunch of algorithms, such as `seq_phragmen`, `phragmms`, and further optimizations like `balancing`.

[`frame-election-provider-support`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_election_provider_support/index.html) is the interface of using these elections within FRAME. it contains some types, traits, and abstractions around this. An important trait here is `ElectionProvider`. This is the trait that needs to be implemented for some type, so it can provide the NPoS election to `pallet-staking`, via `type ElectionProvider`.

[`election-provider-muli-phase`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_election_provider_multi_phase/index.html) is one opinionated implementation of `ElectionProvider`, which has extensive documentation in itself about what it does and how it does it. But end of the day, it can be plugged into `pallet-staking` as [`type ElectionProvider`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_staking/trait.Config.html#associatedtype.ElectionProvider).

One of the details of `election-provider-muli-phase` is that it has miners that run on `OffchainWorker` threads of each block, and compute an election, under certain condition. `type Solver` will determine which algorithm we want to use for this case. The documentation for [`type Solver`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_election_provider_multi_phase/pallet/trait.Config.html#associatedtype.Solver) explains this further.

Alternatively, you can look into [what other types implement `ElectionProvider`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_election_provider_support/trait.ElectionProvider.html#implementors) for more simpler ones.

Finally, `pallet-elections-phragmen` has nothing to do with any of this, and is a generic pallet capable of running onchain elections, and it is directly using `sp-npos-elections::seq_phragmen`. unlike `election-provider-muli-phase` which is quite complicated and has a lot of internal state, this one us quite simple. In reality, this can only be used for some small-scale election that happens onchain, like a council election in Polkadot.

This [recent YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qVd9lAudynY) is a great in-depth explanation of all of this.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I see that if one uses election-provider-multi-phase, one still has to supply a type Fallback which also requires it to implement ElectionProvider. Seeing the types implementing ElectionProvider, besides `OnChainSeqPhragmen`, we don't have many options to choose from. Why is that the case? I am currently using OnChainSeqPhragmen for type Fallback as `NoElection` and `NoFallback` don't particularly strike as "useful", and I guess they are merely provided for testing purposes.

Comment: `NoFallback` is useful in this scenario: https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_election_provider_multi_phase/index.html#emergency-phase